# Git commit history by "time added to branch"

Tags: git

In Git, it is possible to have e.g. a topic branch which contains one or more commits that are dated when the commit is created. Some time later, those commits can be added to a different branch, generally via merge or rebase.

Normally, `git log` will show a list of commits ordered by the date & time the commit was created. Is it possible to view this list based on the date & time *the commit was added to the current branch*? More specifically, I'm looking to write a script that will return to me *a list of commits added to the branch in the last week*, regardless of when the commit was created.

A simple example:

Suppose a commit is created in the branch `topic` on July 22nd. A few days later, on July 25th, the `topic` branch is merged into `master`. If I run my hypothetical `list-commits` script, asking for all commits which were added *on or after July 25th*, I **would** want the aforementioned commit to show up, since it was *merged on July 25th,* even though it was *created on July 22nd.*

One extra note is that, in my typical Git workflow, I only use fast-forward commits, so when I merge one branch into another, no merge commit is generated. I need a way to retrieve this information without relying on merge commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always write a script that will merge for you, adding an additional commit that describes what was merged.  This approach would give you quite a bit of freedom, since you could modify the master either before or after doing the merge, choosing the arrangement that gives you the best results.

**Edit**

`git reflog` might give you the information you're missing.  With a bit of work,

Comment: This would work in theory, but creating extra commits just to implement a "commit digest" script seems ... messy.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy:  Hmmmm...  Would `git reflog` meet  your needs?

Comment: I think `git reflog` does contain the right information, but it's not in a particularly usable format. For one, when I `git rebase` a topic branch onto new commits on master, all of the commits in my topic branch are listed in the reflog as they are played back on top of the new base. This could of course be analyzed programatically, but it might take some effort. Is there a way to make `git reflog` display only the FIRST time HEAD pointed to a unique commit? Also, for a merge it doesn't seem to list the commits individually. Is there any way to get it to do this ala rebases?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to reverse any merges in the branch to determine when the commits were added to the branch. Other than that, only the time of the commit is stored.

Basically, find any merge commits and determine the order of events via those.

Comment: I generally only do fast-forward merges, so no merge commit is generated. Is there some alternative in this case?

Comment: Good question. I'd edit your original question with this clarification and see if anyone else has an answer.